# MySampleApplication clickme button does not appear when deployed to container

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I have built a new project using GWT.  If I run the project from the Intellij IDEA IDE after a few seconds the 'clickme' control appears in the browser and everything works as expected.

I have created an artifact for a application war file, which is created in the expected ../out/artifact folder.

When I deploy the .war file to apache tomcat, and click on the webapp in the apache tomcat manager I just get the list of files under the webapps/MySampleApplication file location.

If I select the MySampleAppliacation.html file I see the text in that html file but the 'clickme' button never appears.

I have done a lot of googling but have not solved the problem.  I checked and the gwt-user.jar file is in the lib folder of the webapp.

This is the GWT control file

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.0//EN"
    "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.0/distro-source/core/src /gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="MySampleApplication">
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                  -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                   -->
<entry-point class='com.mySampleApplication.client.MySampleApplication'/>


<!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->
<servlet path='/MySampleApplicationService' class='com.mySampleApplication.server.MySampleApplicationServiceImpl'/>
</module>
```

This is the project html page

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wrapper HTML for App</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MySampleApplication.css">

    <!--                                            -->
    <!-- This script is required bootstrap stuff.   -->
    <!--                                            -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
            src="MySampleApplication/MySampleApplication.nocache.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Sample Application</h1>

<p>
    This is an example of a host page for the App application.
    You can attach a Web Toolkit module to any HTML page you like,
    making it easy to add bits of AJAX functionality to existing pages
    without starting from scratch.
</p>

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td id="slot1"></td>
        <td id="slot2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

For good measure, here are all the files under webapps for this project

```
MySampleApplication\index.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication.css
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication.html
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\0651E8A6D149EEF5E6386F087426CF0A.cache.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\0CE0D511D927FEB65BA6F6D96F24D2D4.cache.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\3C8C88AE707243315A0D688BD60B8CCA.cache.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\4A4AEE91A97252CBA376B9B27863F6ED.cache.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\644584634D68B773C08A73FA726669A5.gwt.rpc
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\clear.cache.gif
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\D003F7646BFEF3B8BE562132E77EFE59.cache.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\hosted.html
MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication\MySampleApplication.nocache.js
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\web.xml
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\MySampleApplication.gwt.xml
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\server
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client\MySampleApplication$1.class
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client\MySampleApplication$MyAsyncCallback.class
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client\MySampleApplication.class
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client\MySampleApplicationService$App.class
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client\MySampleApplicationService.class
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\client\MySampleApplicationServiceAsync.class
MySampleApplication\WEB-INF\classes\com\mySampleApplication\server\MySampleApplicationServiceImpl.class
```

About the only other thing would be the IDEA project module settings......

I am VERY appreciative or your help Andy.

Comment: Do you see the `.nocache.js` file in the war directory? Is your `MySampleApplication.html` file loading the JavaScript file using the line: `<script type="text/javascript" src=".../....nocache.js"`?

Comment: .nocache.js was there BUT I had changed the name of the sample project without changing the name everywhere I should have, so I built another sample project and the file is there as MySampleApplication.nocache.  The script is in the html page (which also had the wrong path in the original sample project.  NOW I get an error in tomcat stderr.out file saying "validateJarFile ....\lib\gwt-user.jar jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class"  (using java 7 and tomcat 6)

Comment: I removed gwt-user.jar from the distribution as research shows it is only needed for compiling.  Now no error in apache log files.  But controls still do not appear, just the list of files.

Comment: Try renaming `MySampleApplication.html` to `index.html` in the deployed application.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that makes the html appear on launch but the sample application controls never appear.

Comment: Please paste your html file into your question. If you just built a new "Hello, World" application then I don't know why there would be a problem when running it in Tomcat.